# DotNetZip in BackgroundWorker update progressbar and label on a form

Tags: c#, backgroundworker, dotnetzip

I'm creating option to backup data of my app with DotNetZip and to avoid freezing the app I've found that the best way for a this type of action best way is to use BackgroundWorker. So I came with something like this:

```
    private void processButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
        worker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(worker_ProgressChanged);
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_RunWorkerCompleted);

        BackupParams bp = new BackupParams();
        bp.Source = inputTextBox.Text;  // source dir
        bp.Output = outputTextBox.Text; // output file
        bp.Password = @"Pa$$w0rd";

        worker.RunWorkerAsync(bp);
    }

    void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show((string)e.Result, "Zip", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }

    void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackupParams bp = (BackupParams)e.Argument;

        string id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        comment += "Created at: " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "\n";
        comment += id;

        ZipFile zf = new ZipFile();
        zf.Comment = comment;
        zf.CompressionMethod = CompressionMethod.BZip2;
        zf.CompressionLevel = CompressionLevel.BestCompression;

        zf.Encryption = EncryptionAlgorithm.WinZipAes256;
        zf.Password = bp.Password;

        zf.Name = bp.Output;

        zf.AddDirectory(bp.Source);

        zf.Save();

        e.Result = bp.Output;
    }
```

and this is BackupParams

```
public class BackupParams
{
    public string Source { get; set; }
    public string Output { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

And right now I'm stuck cause I want to show the progress (percentage with names) of files added to the archive. What is the best way to do this? I know i can use those methods from ZipFile

```
zf.SaveProgress += zf_SaveProgress;
zf.AddProgress += zf_AddProgress;
```

but from those I don't have access progressbar or label that are on form...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sending a progress report out from a BackgroundWorker you use `ReportProgress()` inside your `DoWork` method.

```
void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker theWorker = (BackgroundWorker)sender;
    theWorker.ReportProgress(0, "just starting");

    BackupParams bp = (BackupParams)e.Argument;
    ...
```

This then fires off your `worker_ProgressChanged` method, so you can take the report from there into your controls.

The trick is that you have to make *another* function to handle the progress change with your zip creation. You can't access your UI controls here because they are on a different thread. You should be able to create a lambda for this (and I don't know the exact parameters, please fix if I'm wrong)

```
zf.SaveProgress += (sender, eventArgs) => 
{
    // Check if EvenType equals Saving_AfterWriteEntry or NullReferenceException will be thrown
    if (eventArgs.EventType == ProgressEventType.Saving_AfterWriteEntry)
    {
        theWorker.ReportProgress(eventArgs.EntriesSaved, "Saving "+ eventArgs.CurrentEntry.FileName);
    }
};

zf.AddProgress += (sender, eventArgs) => 
{
    // Check if EventType equals Adding_afterAddEntry or NullReferenceException will be thrown
    if (eventArgs.EventType == ZipProgressEventType.Adding_afterAddEntry)
    {
        theWorker.ReportProgress(eventArgs.EntriesAdded, "Adding "+ eventArgs.CurrentEntry.FileName);
    }
};
```

Comment: i had to modify a bit that lambda expressions to check `eventArgs.EventType` if it's a `ZipProgressEventType.Adding_afterAddEntry` and `ZipProgressEventType.Saving_AfterWriteEntry` or it was throwing `NullReferenceException`

Comment: @gnur2171 done. Now this code works for me. I have progress of saving and names of saved files are shown. Exactly what I was looking for.