# C# Background Worker with zipfile(Ionic.dll)

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

So i have been trying over and over with lots of trial and error and i cannot seem to get this to work, basically i want to unzip a zip file using the Ionic.DLL from http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com as you can see i have also made a thread about it here: [Extract ZipFile Using C# With Progress Report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26571057/extract-zipfile-using-c-sharp-with-progress-report) so to basically sum up what i am after.

I have a form with:
3xbuttons: btnCancel, btnBrowse and btnStart,
1xbackground worker: backgroundworker1
1xlabel: label1
1xtextbox: textBox1
1xprogressbar

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Threading;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using Ionic.Zip;

namespace BackgroundWorkerSample
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The backgroundworker object on which the time consuming operation shall be executed
        /// </summary>
        BackgroundWorker m_oWorker;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            m_oWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
            m_oWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(m_oWorker_DoWork);
            m_oWorker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(m_oWorker_ProgressChanged);
            m_oWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(m_oWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);
            m_oWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            m_oWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// On completed do the appropriate task
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        void m_oWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            //If it was cancelled midway
            if (e.Cancelled)
            {
                lblStatus.Text = "Task Cancelled.";
            }
            else if (e.Error != null)
            {
                lblStatus.Text = "Error while performing background operation.";
            }
            else
            {
                lblStatus.Text = "Task Completed...";
            }
            btnStartAsyncOperation.Enabled = true;
            btnCancel.Enabled = false;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Notification is performed here to the progress bar
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        void m_oWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Here you play with the main UI thread
            progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            lblStatus.Text = "Processing......" + progressBar1.Value.ToString() + "%";
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Time consuming operations go here </br>
        /// i.e. Database operations,Reporting
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        void m_oWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            //NOTE : Never play with the UI thread here...

            //time consuming operation
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                m_oWorker.ReportProgress(i);



                /////////////////////MINEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
                string INSTALL_LOCATION = "C:" + @"\" + "Program Files (x86)" + @"\" + "TEST_FOLDER" + @"\" + @"\" + "Burgos_Folder";
                string DEFAULT_LOCATION = "C:" + @"\" + "Program Files (x86)" + @"\" + "TEST_FOLDER" + @"\" + "test.rar";

                if (!Directory.Exists(INSTALL_LOCATION))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(INSTALL_LOCATION);
                }

                //if the textbox directory exists
                if (Directory.Exists(INSTALL_LOCATION))
                {
                    using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(DEFAULT_LOCATION))
                            {
                                zip.ExtractAll(INSTALL_LOCATION, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
                            }
                }

                //If cancel button was pressed while the execution is in progress
                //Change the state from cancellation ---> cancel'ed
                if (m_oWorker.CancellationPending)
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    m_oWorker.ReportProgress(0);
                    return;
                }

            }

            //Report 100% completion on operation completed
            m_oWorker.ReportProgress(100);
        }

        private void btnStartAsyncOperation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnStartAsyncOperation.Enabled  = false;
            btnCancel.Enabled               = true;
            //Start the async operation here
            m_oWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (m_oWorker.IsBusy)
            {
                //Stop/Cancel the async operation here
                m_oWorker.CancelAsync();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What i would like my winforms to have is simply: browse for a folder, then click Start(btnStart) which starts the zip extraction process which is also shown on the ProgressBar(timewise), and the cancel(btnCancel) button cancels the unzipping processs, i have successfully done everything but i cannot work out how to cancel the unzipping process, it never seems to stop unless i actually close the .exe down. I decided to make a simpler example without the textbox and browse button, and that example is in my previous Asked Question(link above), but i don't see how to implement a way to cancel the unzipping process with the background worker, and i definantly need to use background worker so i can have a progress report on the current situation etc. Can anyone please adapt my examples or provide a example that does this?

Comment: Adapt what examples? You need to post a good code example, with this question. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. In the meantime, make sure you are using the `ProgressChanged` event and have set `WorkerReportsProgress` to `true`.

Comment: You already know about ExtractProgressEventArgs, it has a Cancel property.  So it doesn't take anything more than simply e.Cancel = backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending;

Comment: I have added my current example guys, i thougt linking to my other question with the example was enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution, i have moved away from Ionic and added the existing references: System.IO.Compression and System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.